# How Can I Put Comma in number

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How Can I do this With Ajax?

I have input field

If I start writing Number into the input field

Example:

> 1000000

Turn to this

> 1,000,000

Automatically!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: You probably want to do this client side with jquery. Register on the input a keyup event (https://api.jquery.com/keyup/), and then apply the formatting as proposed by Secular Kid

Comment: AJAX is a technology (short for asynchronous JavaScript and XML) to create asynchronous web applications. It is not used to formt you number output. Do you want to format your numbers in php or in javascript or in jquery?

Comment: I Want do it live ! when im typing the program do it automatically !

Answer (score 1):

Ajax is not required at all. I think you are confused with what AJAX really is. See [this tutorial on AJAX.](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) Whatever you are trying to achieve can be done with Regular Expression, like this :

```
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
} 

var number = numberWithCommas(1000000); //Results 1,000,000
```

**To show this on the screen :**

JavaScript :

```
function myfunc(){
 function numberWithCommas(x) {
        return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
     } 

document.write(numberWithCommas(document.getElementById("input").value));
}
```

HTML :

```
<form>
<input type = "text" id = "input"/>
<button id = "button" onclick = "myfunc()">Go</button>
</form>
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/susexo/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

> See [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp) for a better understanding of Regular Expression.

Comment: I dont understaning !

Comment: how can i show the result ? when user type 100000 in input how it work and turn the number into 100,000 ?

Comment: i call this function in <input  type="text" onchange="numberWothCommas(this)"> but i cant see any result

Comment: I Cant See Any Result With the New Your Code !

Comment: @Mohammad Now it's working, see the updated answer. It also includes a link to the demo.

Comment: yeah ! its work , but i want when user is writing the price comma adds automatically ! do you understand my question ? or explain more ?

Answer (score 0):

Look [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat).

I think it can achieve what you want easily.

Just note it works in IE11+, Chrome & Firefox, and is unavailable in Safari (good job Apple).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the function formatNumber of the [accounting.js library](http://openexchangerates.github.io/accounting.js/).

`accounting.formatNumber(9876543.21, 0, ",")` returns `9'876'543`

Then you also have more function available for output settings as well as number parsing.

Comment: is this javascript functions ? or php ? and how can i call it ?

Answer (score 0):

To add Commas You can use this code:

```
function addCommas(nStr)
{
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}
```

To listen ajax request after complete try this:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
   addCommas("Some strtings ... 10000000 ");
});
```

Comment: how can i call it in html ? when user type the price in input add comma in number 3digits ?