# how can i put commas in thousands?

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
`$.ajax({
                url : "/selectList.do",
                data:{memberNo:memberNo},                   
                success : function(list){
                    console.log(list);
                    for(let i=0;i<list.length;i++){
                             list[i].NUMBER;
                    }
                  }
            });`
```

I got numbers from ajax and I want to put a commas in this number in thousands.

How can I do it?

Comment: Try looking for available answers before asking a new question mate. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2901298/16477430

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32678553/how-can-i-put-comma-in-number
i found this. so i made addCommas function and put 
`$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
           addCommas($(list[i].NUMBER));
        })` in for loop but didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

```js
const thousands = (o) => o.toString().replace(/\B(?<!\.\d*)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');

console.log(thousands(123456789));
console.log(thousands(123456789.123));
```

Or use [Number.prototype.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

```js
const num = 123456.789;

console.log(num.toLocaleString());
```

Or use [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/intl/numberformat)

```js
const number = 123456.789;
const nf = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US');

console.log(nf.format(number));
```

Or use [Array.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

```js
const insert = (arr, index, newItem) => [
  ...arr.slice(0, index),
  newItem,
  ...arr.slice(index)
];

const thousands = (o) => {
  let tmpArr = o.toString().split('.');
  let splitArr = tmpArr[0].split('');
  const reversed = splitArr.reverse();
  for (let i = 1; i <= reversed.length; i++) {
    if (i % 3 == 0)
      splitArr = insert(splitArr, i, ',');
  }
  tmpArr[0] = tmpArr.length > 1 ? '.' : '';
  return splitArr.reverse().concat(tmpArr).join('');
};

console.log(thousands(123456));
console.log(thousands(123456.789));
```